# How to properly clear the cache on Awesomium.NET WPF 1.7.1 while running

Tags: c#, wpf, caching, awesomium

My WebControl is defined in XAML like so

`<aw:WebControl Source="http://google.com" Name="wpfWebControl"/>`

I found [this](http://answers.awesomium.com/questions/1266/how-to-clear-cache-at-runtime.html), and attempted to follow it's instructions by disposing the WebSession and views, like this

```
        var webSession = this.wpfWebControl.WebSession;
        this.wpfWebControl.Dispose();
        webSession.Dispose();
        WebCore.Update();
```

then tried to delete the directory where the cache was stored with a simple

`Directory.Delete(WEBSESSION_CACHE_PATH), true);`

where `WEBSESSION_CACHE_PATH` is the directory where the cache files are stored.

I encounter an UnauthorizedAccessException, therefore the files are still in use. Not only that, if I dispose my WebControl, the screen goes blank, and restoring it with

`this.wpfWebControl = new WebControl()` won't work either.

How am I supposed to do this?

Answer (score 6):

A [`WebSession.ClearCache`](http://docs.awesomium.net/?tc=M_Awesomium_Core_WebSession_ClearCache) has been added in **[v1.7.2](https://www.awesomium.com/download/)**.